# Google Developers Console server error when attempting to create new Client ID

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-drive-api

Using Google Developers Console I have created a new project and am attempting to generate an OAuth Client Id (Credentials for Google API access from Android.)  I select the OAuth option then choose *'Installed Application'* and enter my package name and SHA1 to receive the following error:

> **Server Error**
>
> An internal error occurred: Error (projectid=333333333333) INTERNAL:
>   Failed to update client key.

Any ideas? Am I forced to pay for Silver support since there is no option of contacting Google Cloud tech without it?

I previously had created a Google Developer Console Project with the same package name but ended up deleting the Client ID (and deleting the Project.) I'm thinking that the Google system didn't complete that delete process fully or requires some sort of clean up process since the error message above says failed to 'update' client key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in hopes it may helps others.

Even though I had previously deleted a Client Id with the same Package name and SHA1 fingerprint it apparently still existed somewhere in the Google API system. By navigating to the OLD Google Developer Console this became obvious.

To navigate to the OLD Google Developer Console use the following URL (Note: you must replace 012345678901 with your project id.)

https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect#project:012345678901:access

This confirmed that the Client Id I had previously deleted using the NEW Developer Console still existed somewhere in the system.

After deleting the Client Id using the OLD developer console I was able to create my Client Id in the new console. :)

I'm unsure how much longer the OLD console will be available but I do hope this benefits others.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked out Old console and there is no my undeleted record.
But, I found out that the problem appeares only for published application with release SHA1 key.
I mean, for example I published org.domain.package1 with release sha1 key on Google Play. And after it I get error.
But if I creat client id with package name org.domain.package2 with the same sha1 key it will be created.